# 328 символов из первой правки распространяются на все описания

Tags: поддержка, правки

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/722384/revisions

В версиях 2, 3, 4 и 5 комментарий к правке получился такой:

> в текст добавлено 328 символов

Ну предположим, во 2й действительно 328 символов (ну или было 328 на момент первого изменения), но почему ещё три ревизии словили тот же комментарий?

Comment: Потому что раз Вам лень писать нормальные описания ревизий, то роботам лень считать в них символы. А на самом деле, наверное, какой-нибудь кэш.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что если нажать "править" в пределах 5 минут от вашей последней правки, то вы ещё попадаете под "склеивание правок": изменения будут внесены в ту же ревизию, если с тех пор ничего примечательного не произошло. Поэтому поле для комментария по умолчанию содержит комментарий к текущей ревизии.

Если же вы осуществляете правку довольно долго, и успеваете при открытой форме вылезти за 5-минутный лимит от прошлой, то при сохранении создаётся новая ревизия, но поскольку в форме при сохранении был старый комментарий, то со старым же комментарием.

Повторяем эту процедуру с новой ревизией 4 раза — получается то, то у вас.

---

Починить это, гипотетически, можно, добавив в таблицу ревизий флаг "без описания", который устанавливается при отсутствии комментария от пользователя, и приводит к пустоте этого поля при повторном редактировании. Сервер же, получая пустое поле, должен будет обновить объём изменений или посчитать новый в зависимости от того, попадает ли правка под склейку, или нет; и заполнить комментарий самостоятельно. Если пользователь указывает комментарий явно – флаг не ставить или снимать (при склейке). Отображать наличие этого флага в ревизии можно путём отображения комментария курсивом.

Но проблема косметическая, от её решения пользы мало. Я б не рассчитывал, что это сделают.

Comment: Хорошее объяснение. Но работать **должно** не так. В частности, если вручную описание не вводилось, надо его обновлять при сохранении, а не при начале правки. Но такого признака нет, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: Добавлю, что фиксация правки происходит не только при вылетании за пятиминутный временной диапазон, но и при добавлении комментария и некоторых других действиях.